# Moving the cursor after the inserted word

Tags: vba, ms-word

In my VBA macro I am inserting some text in to the active document.
After the insertion the cursor is not behind the inserted word as It would be if you manually typed it in but before the inserted word. How do I move it?

```
Dim insertedText As String
insertedText = "test"

With ActiveDocument
    .Range.InsertAfter insertedText
    'move the cursor behind insertedText
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, I solved it by adding this piece of code after the with statement

```
Selection.Move wdCharacter, Len(insertedText)
```

Thanks nonetheless!